# How do I enable MP3 preview?

Tags: nautilus, mp3, previews

Just upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 and Nautilus no longer previews MP3 files when I hover over them.

Another PC that's been running 11.10 for a while also experienced this after the latest update

Nautilus preferences no longer show options for media / mp3 files, so how can I get this functionality back?

Comment: About your image previewer question, yes, would be better if it was a separate question. Try the sushi file previewer - http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/install-sushi-file-previewer-in-ubuntu.html A full article is here talking about it.

Comment: It's a pity the GNOME developers chose to remove this functionality. FWIW, KDE's Dolphin still offers extensive preview capabilites.

Answer (score 12):

With [gnome-sushi](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-sushi) installed and then from Nautilus ....

To preview a song left click on the file then press the space bar. Gnome-Sushi will then play the file in a separate window.

Not as simple as the old mouse hover preview, but also better in that you can move the mouse away and it will keep playing until you stop it. If you click on another song the playback will switch to the new selection within the same preview window.

Answer (score 11):

There is also **Gloobus** for preview. Just follow the steps below and you do not even need to restart Nautilus or do anything. Install PPA, Update, install packages, done.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gloobus-dev/gloobus-preview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview gloobus-sushi
```

Gloobus is an alternative to Sushi (Which I find much better since it supports a couple of friendly options) and you can preview Avi files, MKV files, Video files in general, sound files in general, text, pdf, etc... Just press space and PREVIEW. Press space again and preview off. Also you can start previwing a file and use your keyboard arrows to move to another file for preview.

If you are using 13.04+ the following is the install command line:

```
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview
```

Comment: Whow. Just installed it and I find Gloobus preview WAY better than Sushi. Highly recommended! Thanks for this tip :)

Comment: Yes very good program and it opens a lot of things very easy.

Comment: it seems it doesn't work with 12.10 ? Here is the error I received when trying to install it. http://pastebin.com/Uma438DB

Comment: Ok,I followed @rahmat solution and it was installed properly. Thanks you for telling us about the "space"

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge this feature is no longer available in Nautilus (since Nautilus 3.0). You need to use gnome-sushi to preview audio files now.

Comment: I don't know why they removed that wonderful feature from nautilus. It was quite handy to give jaw dropping ubuntu demo to windows users :--(

Answer (score 3):

just install gloobus-preview and don't forget to install ubuntu-restricted-extras

install gloobus-preview:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gloobus-dev/gloobus-preview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview gloobus-sushi libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
```

install ubuntu restricted extras

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

that will work for you