# How can I play songs by just hovering the mouse on them?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable MP3 preview in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64968/how-do-i-enable-mp3-preview-in-11-10)

in ubuntu 11.04 I could play songs by putting the mouse on them. but now in ubuntu 11.10 it doesn't work.
thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You could install [gnome-sushi](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-sushi). It's a previewer for images, audio files and documents. 
Just "sudo apt-get install gnome-sushi" or visit Software Center.

Comment: i installed and it still don't work. any other suggestion? or maybe i need to configure gnome-sushi, but i can't find it after i install it.