# Audio preview gone?

Tags: sound, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable MP3 preview?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64968/how-do-i-enable-mp3-preview)

There used to be the fantastic feature in Nautilus that allowed you to hear a Music file if the cursor hovered over it for a second. This seems to have been taken out. I don't know if it's a Nautilus thing or an Ubuntu thing or even a Gnome3 thing. Someone seems to have cut it. Going into the file manager - edit - preferences - Preview -- only shows me "Text files", "Other previewable files", and "Folders". None of these has a "sound" option.
I've read "fixes" that include installing mpg321 and checking the "sound section". Nothing seems to work.
This feature is brilliant and I want it back! When I'm making noise collages in audacity for the theater - it's so helpful to go through my sound library by just hovering over the files. I don't have to "right click - open with" and wait for 7 seconds until some audio player opens the tracks. 
If we're talking "productivity" here then this feature must come back! The question is "Who ditched it?" Nautilus, Ubuntu, or Gnome3?
Anyboby got any ideas how to get it back? Is there something other than mpg321 that I can install?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Shushi Previewer:

sudo apt-get install gnome-sushi

Then, u can preview all files, included audio files pressing the spacebar. ;)