# No Music Preview on mouse hover over music file as in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable MP3 preview?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64968/how-do-i-enable-mp3-preview)

No Music Preview on mouse hover over music file as in Ubuntu 11.04.

I cannot see the small play icon on the top of the music file when I place my mouse over it.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was lost with the upgrade to gnome 3/nautilus 3

You can use a preview plugin like gnome-sushi or gloobus preview though (I prefer gloobus-preview)