# sound preview / vista previa de archivos de sonido

Tags: indicator-sound

Me gustaría volver a tener vista previa en los archivos de sonido como en las versiones anteriores de ubuntu cuando pasaba el muose  por encima del icono.

### Gracias

I want hear a preview sound when I put the mouse's arrow over sound's icons.
                                                   thanks

Answer (score 1):

**English**
The actual preview function like before is gone in Nautilus 3.x. The closer you can get is in this question: [How do I enable MP3 preview?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64968/how-do-i-enable-mp3-preview) but is not the same. The option might be available in the future but until now there is no confirmation that it will be the same as before.

**Español**
La funcion de vista previa como se podia hacer antes ha sido eliminada en Nautilus 3.x. Lo mas cercano que puedes estar es encontrado en esta pregunta: [How do I enable MP3 preview?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64968/how-do-i-enable-mp3-preview) pero no es lo mismo. La opcion podria estar disponible en el futuro pero aun no se tiene confirmacion sobre esto.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the elimination of preview files is not very accurate. Many of my friends who use other OS this function are very impressive and is a good presentation of Ubuntu