# Play sound when pointer is on the icon

Tags: sound, music-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable MP3 preview?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64968/how-do-i-enable-mp3-preview)

As far as i can remember, which must have been Maverick Meercat it was possible to play audio file just by hovering on it with the pointer. 
This is no longer happening (Oneiric Ocelot), have i uninstalled something? Did Ubuntu not ship with a default app anymore that used to do this?

Answer (score 0):

yes that feature is dropped!(I also miss it), But you can use SUSHI PREVIEWER for the same thing (but it is different)you need to press space to preview,the advantage is, it previews many media files(Music,Photos,etc..) Read [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html) for more details