# Space bar plays music or video

Tags: sound

My ubuntu used to play music or vids by pushing the space bar while the cursor is over the file. How can I get this back on 14.10?

Comment: Seems to me like this is what you need: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64968/how-do-i-enable-mp3-preview

Comment: It depends on what program you use. What program do you use? GNOME MPlayer, VLC media player, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can just go

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-sushi
```

This will install **gnome-sushi** which enables such preview functionality on nautilus. I'm not sure about other file managers.

It can preview music, photos, videos and folders. It uses a slick window to do this, with all basic functionality available such as pausing and skipping..etc

Comment: In general, it's good practice to post a little explanation to go along with commands that you suggest. In this case, since you're suggesting install software, it might be good to explain what this software does.

Comment: Thanks @michaelms. Advice taken. I modified the response.